# PHP Curl download file to server save as utf-8

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to download a file to server with curl.  I'm having a problem with the filename and saving. The filename is in persian but when i check the file in filezilla it is encoded incorrectly.  It should still show the persian character.

For example the file name is:
`حواشی ثبت نام دوازدهمین دوره ریاست جمهوری/ خنده دار - قسمت هفتم (7)`

But when i check filezilla the filename is:
 `â«ÙÛÙÙ Ø³ÛÙÙØ§ÛÛ ÙØ±Ø¯ÙØ§ ÙØ±Ø´ØªÙ Ù.mp4`

curl.php

```
$destination = "/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/my_channels/videos/".$videoTitle.".mp4";
        $file = fopen($destination, 'w');


        // cURL
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
        // set cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
        // set file handler option
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
        // execute cURL
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        // close cURL
        curl_close($ch);
        // close file
        fclose($file);
```

How do i get the filename to have the persian characters?

Comment: urlencode() maybe can help

Comment: That *is* UTF8, but FileZilla seems to be displaying it as ISO8859. This is a problem with the negotiation between your FTP server and FileZilla. https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Encoding#UTF8_feature_negotiation

Comment: I've checked in filemanager in cpanel and still the same.